# Не работает атрибут android:drawableStart

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Очень странная проблема, в button не отображает изображение именно android:drawableStart, причем остальные схожие атрибуты успешно работают drawableEnd, drawableRight, drawableLeft, drawableTop и т.д.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/previous_button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/arrow_left"/>
```

Comment: Если у вас стрелка влево зачем вам drawableStart? Вы хотите чтобы у пользователей RTL справа была стрелка указывающая налево?

Comment: В целом интересно с чем связана данная проблема, т.к. на всех элементах drawableStart не работает